# Material-UI: Slider - How to increase the height of slider/track

Tags: material-ui

I am trying to increase the height of slider/track of slider component.

I have been trying to set style and sliderStyle, but no luck yet.

I was looking at the code and it seems does not allow us to set css style down to that level.

```
return (
  <div {...other} style={prepareStyles(Object.assign({}, style))}>
    <span>{description}</span>
    <span>{error}</span>
    <div
      style={prepareStyles(Object.assign({}, styles.slider, sliderStyle))}
      onFocus={this.handleFocus}
      onBlur={this.handleBlur}
      onMouseDown={this.handleMouseDown}
      onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseEnter}
      onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseLeave}
      onMouseUp={this.handleMouseUp}
      onTouchStart={this.handleTouchStart}
      onKeyDown={!disabled && this.handleKeyDown}
    >
      <div ref={(node) => this.track = node} style={prepareStyles(styles.track)}>
        <div style={prepareStyles(styles.filled)} />
        <div style={prepareStyles(styles.remaining)} />
        <div
          ref={(node) => this.handle = node}
          style={prepareStyles(handleStyles)}
          tabIndex={0}
        >
          {!disabled && !disableFocusRipple && (
            <FocusRipple
              style={rippleStyle}
              innerStyle={styles.rippleInner}
              show={(hovered || focused) && !active}
              color={styles.rippleColor.fill}
            />
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input
      type="hidden"
      name={name}
      value={value}
      required={required}
      min={min}
      max={max}
      step={step}
    />
  </div>
);
```

Any thought on that?

Thanks,

Comment: Found it.

    
const muiTheme = getMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    accent1Color: deepOrange500,
  },
  slider: {
    trackSize : 50,
    handleSize:50
  },
});

 <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>